# Network operator says "Registered on network" but Why can't I connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, internet, samsung-galaxy-ace

Good afternoon all,

I was originally using a GSM iPhone and I've switched to an android [Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830L](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_ace_s5830-3724.php). I've got some problems connecting to the internet and was wondering if someone could help me resolve the issue.

These are the steps I took from **Settings** >> **Wireless and networks** >> **Mobile networks** >> **Network operators**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've selected SGP-M1-GSM and it says "Registered on network" but I still can't seem to connect to the internet.

[image]

What do I have to do to enable internet connection?

<sub>I'm currently using v2.3.4 if that matters.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this would work, but worth a try. Some mobile phones and some cell phone service providers require the use of APN. Contact your cell phone service provider for the APN.

Comment: Heys cool it's working now (instructions from http://www.unlockit.co.nz/mobilesettings/settings.php?id=220) but it seems to be really slow, like 1 minute per page load. Do you know what may be the problem ?

Comment: @Pacerier That sounds more like a network problem than an Android problem.

Comment: @MatthewRead But its slow yesterday and its still slow today.. (I don't get this problem on the iphone) is it possible that I have my settings set wrongly? Like do I have to turn off/on anything?

Comment: Not sure but see if caching helps.